# Problems converting JSON to panda dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a **JSON** that I am trying to convert but I am facing problems. I have pasted below the JSON and the commands which I am trying. Any help, is appreciated. Thanks

**Context:**

I am looping through several individual rows of a data frame and for each row, I get a seperate JSON. JSON for one of the rows is pasted below. As a reference, I have also pasted a JSON with several (3) rows together.

**What I am trying:**

*One method* I used was to extract each attribute individually but problem is that there are some attributes for which the index doesn't exist and in that case, it gives an error. I tried using try, except but it wasn't working properly.

```
df1['usage_textunits'].iloc[[0]]=response['usage']['text_units']
df1['usage_textcharacters'].iloc[[0]]=response['usage']['text_characters']
.....
df1['keyword3text'].iloc[[i]]=response[i]['keywords'][2]['text']
df1['keyword3score'].iloc[[i]]=response[i]['keywords'][2]['sentiment']['score']
```

The *second method*, I tried using normalize but I am unable to find a proper way in there to normalize.

```
ot1 = pd.json_normalize(response[1], record_path = ['keywords',['emotion', ['sadness']]], meta = ['language','usage', 'sentiment'])
```

Sample JSON

```
{'usage': {'text_units': 1, 'text_characters': 43, 'features': 7},
 'syntax': {'tokens': [{'text': 'With',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
    'location': [0, 4],
    'lemma': 'with'},
   {'text': 'great',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
    'location': [5, 10],
    'lemma': 'great'},
   {'text': 'power',
    'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
    'location': [11, 16],
    'lemma': 'power'},
   {'text': 'comes',
    'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
    'location': [17, 22],
    'lemma': 'come'},
   {'text': 'great',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
    'location': [23, 28],
    'lemma': 'great'},
   {'text': 'responsibility',
    'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
    'location': [29, 43],
    'lemma': 'responsibility'}],
  'sentences': [{'text': 'With great power comes great responsibility',
    'location': [0, 43]}]},
 'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.9923, 'label': 'positive'}},
 'language': 'en',
 'keywords': [{'text': 'great power',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.9923, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 1,
   'emotion': {'sadness': 0.024289,
    'joy': 0.81404,
    'fear': 0.032559,
    'disgust': 0.011021,
    'anger': 0.018008},
   'count': 1},
  {'text': 'great responsibility',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.9923, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 0.999529,
   'emotion': {'sadness': 0.024289,
    'joy': 0.81404,
    'fear': 0.032559,
    'disgust': 0.011021,
    'anger': 0.018008},
   'count': 1}],
 'entities': [],
 'emotion': {'document': {'emotion': {'sadness': 0.024289,
    'joy': 0.81404,
    'fear': 0.032559,
    'disgust': 0.011021,
    'anger': 0.018008}}},
 'concepts': [],
 'categories': [{'score': 0.708202,
   'label': '/business and industrial/energy/electricity'},
  {'score': 0.684766, 'label': '/society/unrest and war'},
  {'score': 0.679084, 'label': '/law, govt and politics'}]}
```

---

Sample of 3 rows together put in a single JSON

```
{'usage': {'text_units': 1, 'text_characters': 43, 'features': 7},
 'syntax': {'tokens': [{'text': 'With',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
    'location': [0, 4],
    'lemma': 'with'},
   {'text': 'great',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
    'location': [5, 10],
    'lemma': 'great'},
   {'text': 'power',
    'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
    'location': [11, 16],
    'lemma': 'power'},
   {'text': 'comes',
    'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
    'location': [17, 22],
    'lemma': 'come'},
   {'text': 'great',
    'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
    'location': [23, 28],
    'lemma': 'great'},
   {'text': 'responsibility',
    'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
    'location': [29, 43],
    'lemma': 'responsibility'}],
  'sentences': [{'text': 'With great power comes great responsibility',
    'location': [0, 43]}]},
 'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.9923, 'label': 'positive'}},
 'language': 'en',
 'keywords': [{'text': 'great power',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.9923, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 1,
   'emotion': {'sadness': 0.024289,
    'joy': 0.81404,
    'fear': 0.032559,
    'disgust': 0.011021,
    'anger': 0.018008},
   'count': 1},
  {'text': 'great responsibility',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.9923, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 0.999529,
   'emotion': {'sadness': 0.024289,
    'joy': 0.81404,
    'fear': 0.032559,
    'disgust': 0.011021,
    'anger': 0.018008},
   'count': 1}],
 'entities': [],
 'emotion': {'document': {'emotion': {'sadness': 0.024289,
    'joy': 0.81404,
    'fear': 0.032559,
    'disgust': 0.011021,
    'anger': 0.018008}}},
 'concepts': [],
 'categories': [{'score': 0.708202,
   'label': '/business and industrial/energy/electricity'},
  {'score': 0.684766, 'label': '/society/unrest and war'},
  {'score': 0.679084, 'label': '/law, govt and politics'}],
 0: {'usage': {'text_units': 1, 'text_characters': 29, 'features': 7},
  'syntax': {'tokens': [{'text': 'Aw',
     'part_of_speech': 'PROPN',
     'location': [0, 2]},
    {'text': 'no', 'part_of_speech': 'INTJ', 'location': [3, 5]},
    {'text': 'bless',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [6, 11],
     'lemma': 'bless'},
    {'text': 'you',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [12, 15],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': 'u', 'part_of_speech': 'AUX', 'location': [16, 17]},
    {'text': 'look',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [18, 22],
     'lemma': 'look'},
    {'text': 'fab',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
     'location': [23, 26],
     'lemma': 'fab'},
    {'text': '', 'part_of_speech': 'NOUN', 'location': [27, 28]},
    {'text': '',
     'part_of_speech': 'SYM',
     'location': [28, 29],
     'lemma': ''}],
   'sentences': [{'text': 'Aw no bless you u look fab ',
     'location': [0, 29]}]},
  'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.884736, 'label': 'positive'}},
  'language': 'en',
  'keywords': [{'text': 'fab ',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.884736, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.75344,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.044852,
     'joy': 0.855532,
     'fear': 0.036888,
     'disgust': 0.030614,
     'anger': 0.001655},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'Aw',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.884736, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.24656,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.044852,
     'joy': 0.855532,
     'fear': 0.036888,
     'disgust': 0.030614,
     'anger': 0.001655},
    'count': 1}],
  'entities': [],
  'emotion': {'document': {'emotion': {'sadness': 0.044852,
     'joy': 0.855532,
     'fear': 0.036888,
     'disgust': 0.030614,
     'anger': 0.001655}}},
  'concepts': [],
  'categories': [{'score': 0.613374, 'label': '/style and fashion'},
   {'score': 0.548041, 'label': "/style and fashion/men's fashion"},
   {'score': 0.534872, 'label': '/style and fashion/clothing/skirts'}]},
 1: {'usage': {'text_units': 1, 'text_characters': 154, 'features': 7},
  'syntax': {'tokens': [{'text': 'You',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [0, 3],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': 'are',
     'part_of_speech': 'AUX',
     'location': [4, 7],
     'lemma': 'be'},
    {'text': 'so',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADV',
     'location': [8, 10],
     'lemma': 'so'},
    {'text': 'gorgeous',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
     'location': [11, 19],
     'lemma': 'gorgeous'},
    {'text': 'loving',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [20, 26],
     'lemma': 'love'},
    {'text': 'the',
     'part_of_speech': 'DET',
     'location': [27, 30],
     'lemma': 'the'},
    {'text': 'makeup',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [31, 37],
     'lemma': 'makeup'},
    {'text': 'products',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [38, 46],
     'lemma': 'product'},
    {'text': '.', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [46, 47]},
    {'text': 'We',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [48, 50],
     'lemma': 'we'},
    {'text': 'can',
     'part_of_speech': 'AUX',
     'location': [51, 54],
     'lemma': 'can'},
    {'text': 'really',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADV',
     'location': [55, 61],
     'lemma': 'really'},
    {'text': 'dress',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [62, 67],
     'lemma': 'dress'},
    {'text': 'up',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [68, 70],
     'lemma': 'up'},
    {'text': 'and',
     'part_of_speech': 'CCONJ',
     'location': [71, 74],
     'lemma': 'and'},
    {'text': 'put',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [75, 78],
     'lemma': 'put'},
    {'text': 'our',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [79, 82],
     'lemma': 'our'},
    {'text': 'makeup',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [83, 89],
     'lemma': 'makeup'},
    {'text': 'on',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [90, 92],
     'lemma': 'on'},
    {'text': 'for',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [93, 96],
     'lemma': 'for'},
    {'text': 'night',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [97, 102],
     'lemma': 'night'},
    {'text': 'out',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADV',
     'location': [103, 106],
     'lemma': 'out'},
    {'text': 'with',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [107, 111],
     'lemma': 'with'},
    {'text': 'our',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [112, 115],
     'lemma': 'our'},
    {'text': 'friends',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [116, 123],
     'lemma': 'friend'},
    {'text': 'and',
     'part_of_speech': 'CCONJ',
     'location': [124, 127],
     'lemma': 'and'},
    {'text': 'family',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [128, 134],
     'lemma': 'family'},
    {'text': '❤️', 'part_of_speech': 'NUM', 'location': [135, 137]},
    {'text': '❤️', 'part_of_speech': 'NUM', 'location': [137, 139]},
    {'text': '❤️', 'part_of_speech': 'NUM', 'location': [139, 141]},
    {'text': '@thegeorgiaedit',
     'part_of_speech': 'X',
     'location': [142, 157]}],
   'sentences': [{'text': 'You are so gorgeous loving the makeup products.',
     'location': [0, 47]},
    {'text': 'We can really dress up and put our makeup on for night out with our friends and family ❤️❤️❤️ @thegeorgiaedit',
     'location': [48, 157]}]},
  'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.999134, 'label': 'positive'}},
  'language': 'en',
  'keywords': [{'text': 'makeup products',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.992422, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.943771,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.035518,
     'joy': 0.94424,
     'fear': 0.003142,
     'disgust': 0.001571,
     'anger': 0.004537},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'night',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.988062, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.618204,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.049703,
     'joy': 0.881541,
     'fear': 0.046596,
     'disgust': 0.019083,
     'anger': 0.013096},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'friends',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.988062, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.59808,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.049703,
     'joy': 0.881541,
     'fear': 0.046596,
     'disgust': 0.019083,
     'anger': 0.013096},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'makeup',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.988062, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.587994,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.033005,
     'joy': 0.935868,
     'fear': 0.019793,
     'disgust': 0.007058,
     'anger': 0.005957},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'family',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.988062, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.581226,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.049703,
     'joy': 0.881541,
     'fear': 0.046596,
     'disgust': 0.019083,
     'anger': 0.013096},
    'count': 1}],
  'entities': [{'type': 'TwitterHandle',
    'text': '@thegeorgiaedit',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.988062, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.531553,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.049703,
     'joy': 0.881541,
     'fear': 0.046596,
     'disgust': 0.019083,
     'anger': 0.013096},
    'count': 1,
    'confidence': 0.8}],
  'emotion': {'document': {'emotion': {'sadness': 0.033005,
     'joy': 0.935868,
     'fear': 0.019793,
     'disgust': 0.007058,
     'anger': 0.005957}}},
  'concepts': [{'text': 'Interpersonal relationship',
    'relevance': 0.849278,
    'dbpedia_resource': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Interpersonal_relationship'},
   {'text': 'Marriage',
    'relevance': 0.849028,
    'dbpedia_resource': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Marriage'}],
  'categories': [{'score': 0.999999,
    'label': '/style and fashion/beauty/cosmetics/eyeshadow'}]},
 2: {'usage': {'text_units': 1, 'text_characters': 73, 'features': 7},
  'syntax': {'tokens': [{'text': 'Omg',
     'part_of_speech': 'INTJ',
     'location': [0, 3]},
    {'text': 'your',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [4, 8],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': 'eye',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [9, 12],
     'lemma': 'eye'},
    {'text': '!', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [12, 13]},
    {'text': 'I',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [14, 15],
     'lemma': 'I'},
    {'text': '’ve',
     'part_of_speech': 'AUX',
     'location': [15, 18],
     'lemma': 'have'},
    {'text': 'done',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [19, 23],
     'lemma': 'do'},
    {'text': 'that',
     'part_of_speech': 'SCONJ',
     'location': [24, 28],
     'lemma': 'that'},
    {'text': 'many',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
     'location': [29, 33],
     'lemma': 'many'},
    {'text': 'of',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [34, 36],
     'lemma': 'of'},
    {'text': 'times',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [37, 42],
     'lemma': 'time'},
    {'text': ',', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [42, 43]},
    {'text': 'haha', 'part_of_speech': 'INTJ', 'location': [44, 48]},
    {'text': '.', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [48, 49]},
    {'text': 'I',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [50, 51],
     'lemma': 'I'},
    {'text': 'hope',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [52, 56],
     'lemma': 'hope'},
    {'text': 'you',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [57, 60],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': '’re',
     'part_of_speech': 'AUX',
     'location': [60, 63],
     'lemma': 'be'},
    {'text': 'okay',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
     'location': [64, 68],
     'lemma': 'okay'},
    {'text': '?', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [68, 69]},
    {'text': 'Xxx', 'part_of_speech': 'PROPN', 'location': [70, 73]}],
   'sentences': [{'text': 'Omg your eye!', 'location': [0, 13]},
    {'text': 'I’ve done that many of times, haha.', 'location': [14, 49]},
    {'text': 'I hope you’re okay?', 'location': [50, 69]},
    {'text': 'Xxx', 'location': [70, 73]}]},
  'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.718389, 'label': 'positive'}},
  'language': 'en',
  'keywords': [{'text': 'eye',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.46666, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.646884,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.197723,
     'joy': 0.204684,
     'fear': 0.558237,
     'disgust': 0.171825,
     'anger': 0.039248},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'times',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0.795969, 'label': 'positive'},
    'relevance': 0.646884,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.065955,
     'joy': 0.829682,
     'fear': 0.053446,
     'disgust': 0.021283,
     'anger': 0.030311},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'Xxx',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0, 'label': 'neutral'},
    'relevance': 0.646884,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0, 'joy': 0, 'fear': 0, 'disgust': 0, 'anger': 0},
    'count': 1}],
  'entities': [],
  'emotion': {'document': {'emotion': {'sadness': 0.021076,
     'joy': 0.40877,
     'fear': 0.23572,
     'disgust': 0.435839,
     'anger': 0.036133}}},
  'concepts': [{'text': 'The Daily Telegraph',
    'relevance': 0.866326,
    'dbpedia_resource': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Daily_Telegraph'},
   {'text': 'The Sun',
    'relevance': 0.755733,
    'dbpedia_resource': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Sun_(newspaper)'}],
  'categories': [{'score': 0.551338,
    'label': '/business and industrial/business software'},
   {'score': 0.534767, 'label': '/business and industrial/business news'},
   {'score': 0.527439, 'label': '/art and entertainment/shows and events'}]},
 3: {'usage': {'text_units': 1, 'text_characters': 94, 'features': 7},
  'syntax': {'tokens': [{'text': 'What',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [0, 4],
     'lemma': 'what'},
    {'text': 'happened',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [5, 13],
     'lemma': 'happen'},
    {'text': 'to',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [14, 16],
     'lemma': 'to'},
    {'text': 'your',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [17, 21],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': 'eye',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [22, 25],
     'lemma': 'eye'},
    {'text': 'honey',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [26, 31],
     'lemma': 'honey'},
    {'text': '???', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [31, 34]},
    {'text': 'I',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [35, 36],
     'lemma': 'I'},
    {'text': 'saw',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [37, 40],
     'lemma': 'saw'},
    {'text': 'you',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [41, 44],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': 'covering',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [45, 53],
     'lemma': 'cover'},
    {'text': 'up',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [54, 56],
     'lemma': 'up'},
    {'text': 'with',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [57, 61],
     'lemma': 'with'},
    {'text': 'makeup',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [62, 68],
     'lemma': 'makeup'},
    {'text': 'but',
     'part_of_speech': 'CCONJ',
     'location': [69, 72],
     'lemma': 'but'},
    {'text': 'missed',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [73, 79],
     'lemma': 'miss'},
    {'text': 'if',
     'part_of_speech': 'SCONJ',
     'location': [80, 82],
     'lemma': 'if'},
    {'text': 'you',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [83, 86],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': 'said',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [87, 91],
     'lemma': 'say'},
    {'text': 'it',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [92, 94],
     'lemma': 'it'}],
   'sentences': [{'text': 'What happened to your eye honey???',
     'location': [0, 34]},
    {'text': 'I saw you covering up with makeup but missed if you said it',
     'location': [35, 94]}]},
  'sentiment': {'document': {'score': -0.793038, 'label': 'negative'}},
  'language': 'en',
  'keywords': [{'text': 'eye honey',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0, 'label': 'neutral'},
    'relevance': 0.804643,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.205815,
     'joy': 0.310033,
     'fear': 0.212794,
     'disgust': 0.080477,
     'anger': 0.024762},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'makeup',
    'sentiment': {'score': -0.843195, 'label': 'negative'},
    'relevance': 0.649373,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.821988,
     'joy': 0.031067,
     'fear': 0.155549,
     'disgust': 0.151681,
     'anger': 0.063043},
    'count': 1}],
  'entities': [],
  'emotion': {'document': {'emotion': {'sadness': 0.781661,
     'joy': 0.035912,
     'fear': 0.215303,
     'disgust': 0.149637,
     'anger': 0.042716}}},
  'concepts': [{'text': 'What Happened',
    'relevance': 0.886784,
    'dbpedia_resource': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/What_Happened'}],
  'categories': [{'score': 1.0,
    'label': '/style and fashion/beauty/cosmetics/eyeshadow'}]},
 4: {'usage': {'text_units': 1, 'text_characters': 101, 'features': 7},
  'syntax': {'tokens': [{'text': 'What',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [0, 4],
     'lemma': 'what'},
    {'text': 'happened',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [5, 13],
     'lemma': 'happen'},
    {'text': 'to',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [14, 16],
     'lemma': 'to'},
    {'text': 'your',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [17, 21],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': 'eye',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [22, 25],
     'lemma': 'eye'},
    {'text': '?', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [25, 26]},
    {'text': 'I',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [27, 28],
     'lemma': 'I'},
    {'text': 'was',
     'part_of_speech': 'AUX',
     'location': [29, 32],
     'lemma': 'be'},
    {'text': 'out',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [33, 36],
     'lemma': 'out'},
    {'text': 'of',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [37, 39],
     'lemma': 'of'},
    {'text': 'social',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
     'location': [40, 46],
     'lemma': 'social'},
    {'text': 'media',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [47, 52],
     'lemma': 'media'},
    {'text': 'for',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADP',
     'location': [53, 56],
     'lemma': 'for'},
    {'text': 'a', 'part_of_speech': 'DET', 'location': [57, 58], 'lemma': 'a'},
    {'text': 'while',
     'part_of_speech': 'NOUN',
     'location': [59, 64],
     'lemma': 'while'},
    {'text': 'and',
     'part_of_speech': 'CCONJ',
     'location': [65, 68],
     'lemma': 'and'},
    {'text': 'did',
     'part_of_speech': 'AUX',
     'location': [69, 72],
     'lemma': 'do'},
    {'text': 'n’t',
     'part_of_speech': 'PART',
     'location': [72, 75],
     'lemma': 'not'},
    {'text': 'see',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [76, 79],
     'lemma': 'see'},
    {'text': '!', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [79, 80]},
    {'text': 'You',
     'part_of_speech': 'PRON',
     'location': [81, 84],
     'lemma': 'you'},
    {'text': 'look',
     'part_of_speech': 'VERB',
     'location': [85, 89],
     'lemma': 'look'},
    {'text': 'gorgeous',
     'part_of_speech': 'ADJ',
     'location': [90, 98],
     'lemma': 'gorgeous'},
    {'text': '!', 'part_of_speech': 'PUNCT', 'location': [98, 99]},
    {'text': '',
     'part_of_speech': 'SYM',
     'location': [100, 101],
     'lemma': ''}],
   'sentences': [{'text': 'What happened to your eye?', 'location': [0, 26]},
    {'text': 'I was out of social media for a while and didn’t see!',
     'location': [27, 80]},
    {'text': 'You look gorgeous!', 'location': [81, 99]},
    {'text': '', 'location': [100, 101]}]},
  'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.783996, 'label': 'positive'}},
  'language': 'en',
  'keywords': [{'text': 'social media',
    'sentiment': {'score': -0.767261, 'label': 'negative'},
    'relevance': 0.999841,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.09909,
     'joy': 0.104576,
     'fear': 0.051406,
     'disgust': 0.164938,
     'anger': 0.048497},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'eye',
    'sentiment': {'score': 0, 'label': 'neutral'},
    'relevance': 0.611758,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.368063,
     'joy': 0.055232,
     'fear': 0.494946,
     'disgust': 0.057255,
     'anger': 0.022281},
    'count': 1},
   {'text': 'while',
    'sentiment': {'score': -0.767261, 'label': 'negative'},
    'relevance': 0.064339,
    'emotion': {'sadness': 0.09909,
     'joy': 0.104576,
     'fear': 0.051406,
     'disgust': 0.164938,
     'anger': 0.048497},
    'count': 1}],
  'entities': [],
  'emotion': {'document': {'emotion': {'sadness': 0.097837,
     'joy': 0.552542,
     'fear': 0.145148,
     'disgust': 0.074379,
     'anger': 0.007396}}},
  'concepts': [{'text': 'What Happened',
    'relevance': 0.886784,
    'dbpedia_resource': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/What_Happened'}],
  'categories': [{'score': 0.983277,
    'label': '/technology and computing/internet technology/social network'}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ot1 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path = ['keywords'], meta = ['language','usage', 'sentiment', 'emotion'])

ot2 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path = ['categories'], meta = ['language','usage', 'sentiment', 'emotion'])

ot3 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path = ['syntax',['tokens']], meta = ['language','usage', 'sentiment', 'emotion'])

ot4=ot1.append(ot2)

ot5=ot4.append(ot3)
```